# Restrict access to certain users

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection, restrict

I want to setup certain password protected pages but want the pages accessible only to certain users. Do I need to pre-assign usernames and passwords, or is there a way to set up my database so it will detect those users I want to authorize and grant access to?

Comment: Maybe a log in system or if you want, you can go with .htaccess passwords.

Comment: i think what you want to implement is something like an ACL? or access level system? different users have different access levels or roles/positions with different access levels

Answer (score 1):

For such situations, you could use different privileges for users. Set a corresponding session variable to indicate current users privilege level. And of course, you would need to have that information regarding privileges in database.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the code for the variable you would suggest, and do I set the user level to a default setting until the person registers and then if the registrant is an authorized user go into the db ad edit the level?

Comment: @dmwesq: Ideally, when the DB was first created, you should have few users with highest privilege. From thereon, you would design the App to promote users. It would be a cumbersome task to do that directly by editing database table. The entire solution is complex though.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the usernames and passwords in the database, and then check the access rights to the protected pages.

Comment: I realize I can (and in fact must?) store the username and password in the database. But my question is do I need to pre-assign these items to each potential user? I obviously can't have an open registration where anyone can sign up for access, so I am looking at how I can just have certain users be able to register - can I perhaps set some field in the database to a default value that the user would have to enter to be able to register?

Comment: @dmwesq i think your problem is of architectural/design than programming, to answer your question on behalf of Tommy, if I may, is that you have to design your whole system such that when a user registers he will be given a role/group by which you can limit access to some parts of your website for those within the group/role

Comment: I think I found an answer on another site - perhaps adding a userlevel field in database and then controlling access via the userlevel?

Comment: @dmwesq I'd suggest to set up a registration form and either check the email addresses of the future users, if you have them, or have one field for enabling the user, which you set manually after the registration. Or you put them in the database manually with username and password, and let them change afterwards.

Comment: you mean acl? (Access Control List)

Comment: That sounds like what I would be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for my situation was to add to the query AND userlevel='1' and set the db to a default of 0 and change authorized users to 1.